# tomcat 9 not starting on Ubuntu 14.04, stuck in stop/waiting status

Tags: ubuntu, tomcat, ubuntu-14.04

I just installed Tomcat 9 on Ubuntu 14.04 LTE and when I run `sudo service tomcat start`, and then check the status using `sudo service tomcat status`, I get the status: `tomcat stop waiting`.

When I access localhost at port 8080 I get a `Unable to connect`, i.e. it looks like the server is not running.

I followed the tutorial at https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-8-on-ubuntu-14-04 and used the Tomcat 9 file instead of Tomcat 8.

This is how I installed:
(all commands executed without error)

```
sudo groupadd tomcat
sudo useradd -s /bin/false -g tomcat -d /opt/tomcat tomcat
cd ~
wget http://apache.mirror.serversaustralia.com.au/tomcat/tomcat-9/v9.0.0.M10/bin/apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M10.tar.gz
sudo mkdir /opt/tomcat
sudo tar xvf apache-tomcat-8*tar.gz -C /opt/tomcat --strip-components=1
cd /opt/tomcat
sudo chgrp -R tomcat conf
sudo chmod g+rwx conf
sudo chmod g+r conf/*
sudo chown -R tomcat work/ temp/ logs/
// set $JAVA_HOME in /etc/init/tomcat.conf: JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre"
// set in /etc/init/tomcat.conf: env CATALINA_OPTS="-Xms512M -Xmx1024M -server -XX:+UseParallelGC"
sudo initctl reload-configuration
sudo initctl start tomcat
```

Directory listing of /opt/tomcat:
Question 1: is there an issue that the folder access permissions are partly `root` and only some folders are for `tomcat` user? I followed exactly the steps to create the tomcat user and set permissions per the tutorial.

```
vagrant@vagrant:/opt/tomcat$ ll
total 120
drwxr-xr-x 9 root   root    4096 Sep  6 10:03 ./
drwxr-xr-x 4 root   root    4096 Sep  6 10:02 ../
drwxr-x--- 2 root   root    4096 Sep  6 10:03 bin/
drwxrwx--- 2 root   tomcat  4096 Aug 31 15:02 conf/
drwxr-x--- 2 root   root    4096 Sep  6 10:03 lib/
-rw-r----- 1 root   root   57092 Aug 31 15:02 LICENSE
drwxr-x--- 2 tomcat root    4096 Aug 31 15:00 logs/
-rw-r----- 1 root   root    1804 Aug 31 15:02 NOTICE
-rw-r----- 1 root   root    6709 Aug 31 15:02 RELEASE-NOTES
-rw-r----- 1 root   root   15946 Aug 31 15:02 RUNNING.txt
drwxr-x--- 2 tomcat root    4096 Sep  6 10:07 temp/
drwxr-x--- 7 root   root    4096 Aug 31 15:01 webapps/
drwxr-x--- 2 tomcat root    4096 Aug 31 15:00 work/
```

Contents of my /etc/init/tomcat.conf:

```
description "Tomcat Server"

  start on runlevel [2345]
  stop on runlevel [!2345]
  respawn
  respawn limit 10 5

  setuid tomcat
  setgid tomcat

  env JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre
  env CATALINA_HOME=/opt/tomcat

  # Modify these options as needed
  env JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urand$
  env CATALINA_OPTS="-Xms512M -Xmx1024M -server -XX:+UseParallelGC"

  exec $CATALINA_HOME/bin/catalina.sh run

  # cleanup temp directory after stop
  post-stop script
    rm -rf $CATALINA_HOME/temp/*
  end script
```

Directory listing of my `$JAVA_HOME`:

```
vagrant@vagrant:/opt/tomcat$ ll /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
total 28
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 4096 Sep  5 10:36 ./
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Sep  5 10:36 ../
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   22 Apr 22 13:29 ASSEMBLY_EXCEPTION -> jre/ASSEMBLY_EXCEPTION
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Sep  5 10:36 bin/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   41 Apr 22 13:29 docs -> ../../../share/doc/openjdk-8-jre-headless/
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Sep  5 10:36 include/
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Sep  5 10:36 jre/
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Sep  5 10:36 lib/
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Sep  5 10:36 man/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   20 Apr 22 13:29 src.zip -> ../openjdk-8/src.zip
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   22 Apr 22 13:29 THIRD_PARTY_README -> jre/THIRD_PARTY_README
vagrant@vagrant:/opt/tomcat$
```

Check if tomcat is running:

```
vagrant@vagrant:/opt/tomcat$ ps a | grep java
 5724 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto java
vagrant@vagrant:/opt/tomcat$

vagrant@vagrant:/opt/tomcat$ ps -ef | grep tomcat
vagrant   5888  1277  0 10:41 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto tomcat
vagrant@vagrant:/opt/tomcat$
```

Trying to access the logs (empty):

```
root@vagrant:/opt/tomcat/logs# ll
total 8
drwxr-x--- 2 tomcat root 4096 Aug 31 15:00 ./
drwxr-xr-x 9 root   root 4096 Sep  6 11:05 ../
root@vagrant:/opt/tomcat/logs# exit
logout
vagrant@vagrant:/opt/tomcat$
```

Logs:

```
vagrant@vagrant:/opt/tomcat$ ll /var/log/
total 1652
drwxrwxr-x 10 root   syslog   4096 Sep  6 11:04 ./
drwxr-xr-x 12 root   root     4096 Sep  5 10:42 ../
-rw-r--r--  1 root   root    36983 Sep  5 11:29 alternatives.log
drwxr-x---  2 root   adm      4096 Sep  5 10:42 apache2/
drwxr-xr-x  2 root   root     4096 Aug  1 15:48 apt/
-rw-r-----  1 syslog adm     37452 Sep  6 12:17 auth.log
-rw-r--r--  1 root   root     3851 Sep  5 10:41 boot.log
-rw-r--r--  1 root   root    61499 Jul 22  2014 bootstrap.log
-rw-rw----  1 root   utmp        0 Jul 22  2014 btmp
drwxr-xr-x  2 root   root     4096 Apr 12  2014 dist-upgrade/
-rw-r-----  1 root   adm     30426 Sep  5 10:41 dmesg
-rw-r-----  1 root   adm     30966 Sep  5 05:31 dmesg.0
-rw-r-----  1 root   adm      9701 Aug  1 15:53 dmesg.1.gz
-rw-r-----  1 root   adm      9649 Aug  1 15:51 dmesg.2.gz
-rw-r-----  1 root   adm        59 Jul 22  2014 dmesg.3.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 root   root   731982 Sep  6 11:04 dpkg.log
-rw-r--r--  1 root   root    32032 Sep  6 11:03 faillog
-rw-r--r--  1 root   root      644 Sep  5 10:36 fontconfig.log
drwxr-xr-x  2 root   root     4096 Aug  1 15:48 fsck/
drwxr-xr-x  3 root   root     4096 Aug  1 15:51 installer/
-rw-r-----  1 syslog adm    183208 Sep  6 11:04 kern.log
-rw-rw-r--  1 root   utmp   292292 Sep  6 11:03 lastlog
drwxr-s---  2 mysql  adm      4096 Sep  6 11:04 mysql/
-rw-r-----  1 mysql  adm         0 Sep  6 11:04 mysql.err
-rw-r-----  1 mysql  adm         0 Sep  6 11:04 mysql.log
-rw-r-----  1 syslog adm    225676 Sep  6 12:17 syslog
-rw-r--r--  1 root   root   146938 Sep  5 10:41 udev
drwxr-xr-x  2 root   root     4096 Sep  5 10:40 unattended-upgrades/
drwxr-xr-x  2 root   root     4096 Sep  6 11:04 upstart/
-rw-r--r--  1 root   root     1200 Sep  5 05:36 vboxadd-install.log
-rw-r--r--  1 root   root       73 Sep  5 05:36 vboxadd-install-x11.log
-rw-r--r--  1 root   root        1 Sep  5 05:35 VBoxGuestAdditions.log
-rw-r--r--  1 root   root      404 Sep  5 05:35 VBoxGuestAdditions-uninstall.log
-rw-rw-r--  1 root   utmp    22656 Sep  5 10:41 wtmp
vagrant@vagrant:/opt/tomcat$
```

Syslog:

```
vagrant@vagrant:/var/log$ grep -r 'tomcat' .
grep: ./upstart/network-interface-eth0.log: Permission denied
grep: ./upstart/network-interface-lo.log: Permission denied
grep: ./upstart/tomcat.log: Permission denied
grep: ./upstart/kmod.log: Permission denied
grep: ./upstart/systemd-logind.log: Permission denied
grep: ./upstart/mountall.log: Permission denied
grep: ./upstart/console-setup.log: Permission denied
grep: ./upstart/ureadahead.log: Permission denied
grep: ./upstart/mysql.log: Permission denied
grep: ./upstart/networking.log: Permission denied
grep: ./upstart/cryptdisks.log: Permission denied
grep: ./upstart/ureadahead-other.log: Permission denied
grep: ./upstart/gssd.log: Permission denied
grep: ./upstart/statd.log: Permission denied
grep: ./upstart/container-detect.log: Permission denied
grep: ./upstart/procps-virtual-filesystems.log: Permission denied
grep: ./upstart/procps-static-network-up.log: Permission denied
grep: ./upstart/procps.log: Permission denied
grep: ./upstart/rsyslog.log: Permission denied
grep: ./btmp: Permission denied
grep: ./installer/syslog: Permission denied
grep: ./installer/cdebconf/templates.dat: Permission denied
grep: ./installer/cdebconf/questions.dat: Permission denied
grep: ./installer/partman: Permission denied
./syslog:Sep  6 10:05:21 vagrant kernel: [35222.566154] init: /etc/init/tomcat.conf:1: Unknown stanza
./syslog:Sep  6 10:05:39 vagrant kernel: [35241.249677] init: /etc/init/tomcat.conf:1: Unknown stanza
./syslog:Sep  6 10:05:50 vagrant kernel: [35252.042988] init: /etc/init/tomcat.conf:1: Unknown stanza
./syslog:Sep  6 10:06:23 vagrant kernel: [35285.181441] init: /etc/init/tomcat.conf:1: Unknown stanza
./syslog:Sep  6 10:07:26 vagrant kernel: [35348.204413] init: tomcat main process (5583) terminated with status 126
./syslog:Sep  6 10:07:26 vagrant kernel: [35348.204420] init: tomcat main process ended, respawning
./syslog:Sep  6 10:07:26 vagrant kernel: [35348.213247] init: tomcat main process (5587) terminated with status 126
./syslog:Sep  6 10:07:26 vagrant kernel: [35348.213254] init: tomcat main process ended, respawning
./syslog:Sep  6 10:07:26 vagrant kernel: [35348.224530] init: tomcat main process (5591) terminated with status 126
./syslog:Sep  6 10:07:26 vagrant kernel: [35348.224537] init: tomcat main process ended, respawning
./syslog:Sep  6 10:07:26 vagrant kernel: [35348.232944] init: tomcat main process (5595) terminated with status 126
./syslog:Sep  6 10:07:26 vagrant kernel: [35348.232951] init: tomcat main process ended, respawning
./syslog:Sep  6 10:07:26 vagrant kernel: [35348.240516] init: tomcat main process (5599) terminated with status 126
./syslog:Sep  6 10:07:26 vagrant kernel: [35348.240524] init: tomcat main process ended, respawning
./syslog:Sep  6 10:07:26 vagrant kernel: [35348.249047] init: tomcat main process (5603) terminated with status 126
./syslog:Sep  6 10:07:26 vagrant kernel: [35348.249055] init: tomcat main process ended, respawning
./syslog:Sep  6 10:07:26 vagrant kernel: [35348.256800] init: tomcat main process (5607) terminated with status 126
./syslog:Sep  6 10:07:26 vagrant kernel: [35348.256807] init: tomcat main process ended, respawning
./syslog:Sep  6 10:07:26 vagrant kernel: [35348.264498] init: tomcat main process (5611) terminated with status 126
./syslog:Sep  6 10:07:26 vagrant kernel: [35348.264526] init: tomcat main process ended, respawning
./syslog:Sep  6 10:07:26 vagrant kernel: [35348.272763] init: tomcat main process (5615) terminated with status 126
./syslog:Sep  6 10:07:26 vagrant kernel: [35348.272770] init: tomcat main process ended, respawning
./syslog:Sep  6 10:07:26 vagrant kernel: [35348.280498] init: tomcat main process (5619) terminated with status 126
./syslog:Sep  6 10:07:26 vagrant kernel: [35348.280506] init: tomcat main process ended, respawning
./syslog:Sep  6 10:07:26 vagrant kernel: [35348.288651] init: tomcat main process (5623) terminated with status 126
./syslog:Sep  6 10:07:26 vagrant kernel: [35348.288659] init: tomcat respawning too fast, stopped
./syslog:Sep  6 10:24:09 vagrant kernel: [36351.039889] init: tomcat main process (5654) terminated with status 126
./syslog:Sep  6 10:24:09 vagrant kernel: [36351.039896] init: tomcat main process ended, respawning
./syslog:Sep  6 10:24:09 vagrant kernel: [36351.048627] init: tomcat main process (5658) terminated with status 126
./syslog:Sep  6 10:24:09 vagrant kernel: [36351.048634] init: tomcat main process ended, respawning
./syslog:Sep  6 10:24:09 vagrant kernel: [36351.059579] init: tomcat main process (5662) terminated with status 126
./syslog:Sep  6 10:24:09 vagrant kernel: [36351.059589] init: tomcat main process ended, respawning
./syslog:Sep  6 10:24:09 vagrant kernel: [36351.082366] init: tomcat main process (5666) terminated with status 126
./syslog:Sep  6 10:24:09 vagrant kernel: [36351.082374] init: tomcat main process ended, respawning
./syslog:Sep  6 10:24:09 vagrant kernel: [36351.090163] init: tomcat main process (5670) terminated with status 126
./syslog:Sep  6 10:24:09 vagrant kernel: [36351.090170] init: tomcat main process ended, respawning
./syslog:Sep  6 10:24:09 vagrant kernel: [36351.098647] init: tomcat main process (5674) terminated with status 126
./syslog:Sep  6 10:24:09 vagrant kernel: [36351.098679] init: tomcat main process ended, respawning
./syslog:Sep  6 10:24:09 vagrant kernel: [36351.106639] init: tomcat main process (5678) terminated with status 126
./syslog:Sep  6 10:24:09 vagrant kernel: [36351.106647] init: tomcat main process ended, respawning
./syslog:Sep  6 10:24:09 vagrant kernel: [36351.114743] init: tomcat main process (5682) terminated with status 126
./syslog:Sep  6 10:24:09 vagrant kernel: [36351.114750] init: tomcat main process ended, respawning
./syslog:Sep  6 10:24:09 vagrant kernel: [36351.122404] init: tomcat main process (5686) terminated with status 126
./syslog:Sep  6 10:24:09 vagrant kernel: [36351.122412] init: tomcat main process ended, respawning
./syslog:Sep  6 10:24:09 vagrant kernel: [36351.130457] init: tomcat main process (5690) terminated with status 126
./syslog:Sep  6 10:24:09 vagrant kernel: [36351.130465] init: tomcat main process ended, respawning
./syslog:Sep  6 10:24:09 vagrant kernel: [36351.138334] init: tomcat main process (5694) terminated with status 126
./syslog:Sep  6 10:24:09 vagrant kernel: [36351.138342] init: tomcat respawning too fast, stopped
./syslog:Sep  6 10:38:41 vagrant kernel: [37222.764611] init: tomcat main process (5739) terminated with status 126
./syslog:Sep  6 10:38:41 vagrant kernel: [37222.764619] init: tomcat main process ended, respawning
./syslog:Sep  6 10:38:41 vagrant kernel: [37222.773177] init: tomcat main process (5743) terminated with status 126
./syslog:Sep  6 10:38:41 vagrant kernel: [37222.773184] init: tomcat main process ended, respawning
./syslog:Sep  6 10:38:41 vagrant kernel: [37222.786655] init: tomcat main process (5747) terminated with status 126
./syslog:Sep  6 10:38:41 vagrant kernel: [37222.786663] init: tomcat main process ended, respawning
./syslog:Sep  6 10:38:41 vagrant kernel: [37222.794639] init: tomcat main process (5751) terminated with status 126
./syslog:Sep  6 10:38:41 vagrant kernel: [37222.794646] init: tomcat main process ended, respawning
./syslog:Sep  6 10:38:41 vagrant kernel: [37222.802876] init: tomcat main process (5755) terminated with status 126
./syslog:Sep  6 10:38:41 vagrant kernel: [37222.802884] init: tomcat main process ended, respawning
./syslog:Sep  6 10:38:41 vagrant kernel: [37222.810681] init: tomcat main process (5759) terminated with status 126
./syslog:Sep  6 10:38:41 vagrant kernel: [37222.810689] init: tomcat main process ended, respawning
./syslog:Sep  6 10:38:41 vagrant kernel: [37222.818391] init: tomcat main process (5763) terminated with status 126
./syslog:Sep  6 10:38:41 vagrant kernel: [37222.818430] init: tomcat main process ended, respawning
./syslog:Sep  6 10:38:41 vagrant kernel: [37222.826874] init: tomcat main process (5767) terminated with status 126
./syslog:Sep  6 10:38:41 vagrant kernel: [37222.826882] init: tomcat main process ended, respawning
./syslog:Sep  6 10:38:41 vagrant kernel: [37222.834979] init: tomcat main process (5771) terminated with status 126
./syslog:Sep  6 10:38:41 vagrant kernel: [37222.834986] init: tomcat main process ended, respawning
./syslog:Sep  6 10:38:41 vagrant kernel: [37222.843036] init: tomcat main process (5775) terminated with status 126
./syslog:Sep  6 10:38:41 vagrant kernel: [37222.843044] init: tomcat main process ended, respawning
./syslog:Sep  6 10:38:41 vagrant kernel: [37222.850948] init: tomcat main process (5779) terminated with status 126
./syslog:Sep  6 10:38:41 vagrant kernel: [37222.850955] init: tomcat respawning too fast, stopped
./syslog:Sep  6 10:38:51 vagrant kernel: [37233.342798] init: tomcat main process (5792) terminated with status 126
./syslog:Sep  6 10:38:51 vagrant kernel: [37233.342805] init: tomcat main process ended, respawning
./syslog:Sep  6 10:38:51 vagrant kernel: [37233.351367] init: tomcat main process (5796) terminated with status 126
./syslog:Sep  6 10:38:51 vagrant kernel: [37233.351374] init: tomcat main process ended, respawning
./syslog:Sep  6 10:38:51 vagrant kernel: [37233.364019] init: tomcat main process (5800) terminated with status 126
./syslog:Sep  6 10:38:51 vagrant kernel: [37233.364026] init: tomcat main process ended, respawning
./syslog:Sep  6 10:38:51 vagrant kernel: [37233.371726] init: tomcat main process (5804) terminated with status 126
./syslog:Sep  6 10:38:51 vagrant kernel: [37233.371734] init: tomcat main process ended, respawning
./syslog:Sep  6 10:38:51 vagrant kernel: [37233.379759] init: tomcat main process (5808) terminated with status 126
./syslog:Sep  6 10:38:51 vagrant kernel: [37233.379768] init: tomcat main process ended, respawning
./syslog:Sep  6 10:38:51 vagrant kernel: [37233.387833] init: tomcat main process (5812) terminated with status 126
./syslog:Sep  6 10:38:51 vagrant kernel: [37233.387842] init: tomcat main process ended, respawning
./syslog:Sep  6 10:38:51 vagrant kernel: [37233.396662] init: tomcat main process (5816) terminated with status 126
./syslog:Sep  6 10:38:51 vagrant kernel: [37233.396673] init: tomcat main process ended, respawning
./syslog:Sep  6 10:38:51 vagrant kernel: [37233.408969] init: tomcat main process (5820) terminated with status 126
./syslog:Sep  6 10:38:51 vagrant kernel: [37233.408978] init: tomcat main process ended, respawning
./syslog:Sep  6 10:38:51 vagrant kernel: [37233.418558] init: tomcat main process (5824) terminated with status 126
./syslog:Sep  6 10:38:51 vagrant kernel: [37233.418567] init: tomcat main process ended, respawning
./syslog:Sep  6 10:38:51 vagrant kernel: [37233.437261] init: tomcat main process (5828) terminated with status 126
./syslog:Sep  6 10:38:51 vagrant kernel: [37233.437269] init: tomcat main process ended, respawning
./syslog:Sep  6 10:38:51 vagrant kernel: [37233.445168] init: tomcat main process (5832) terminated with status 126
./syslog:Sep  6 10:38:51 vagrant kernel: [37233.445175] init: tomcat respawning too fast, stopped
./syslog:Sep  6 10:40:25 vagrant kernel: [37327.520457] init: tomcat main process (5842) terminated with status 126
./syslog:Sep  6 10:40:25 vagrant kernel: [37327.520465] init: tomcat main process ended, respawning
./syslog:Sep  6 10:40:25 vagrant kernel: [37327.529569] init: tomcat main process (5846) terminated with status 126
./syslog:Sep  6 10:40:25 vagrant kernel: [37327.529577] init: tomcat main process ended, respawning
./syslog:Sep  6 10:40:25 vagrant kernel: [37327.539636] init: tomcat main process (5850) terminated with status 126
./syslog:Sep  6 10:40:25 vagrant kernel: [37327.539643] init: tomcat main process ended, respawning
./syslog:Sep  6 10:40:26 vagrant kernel: [37327.549262] init: tomcat main process (5854) terminated with status 126
./syslog:Sep  6 10:40:26 vagrant kernel: [37327.549270] init: tomcat main process ended, respawning
./syslog:Sep  6 10:40:26 vagrant kernel: [37327.557038] init: tomcat main process (5858) terminated with status 126
./syslog:Sep  6 10:40:26 vagrant kernel: [37327.557046] init: tomcat main process ended, respawning
./syslog:Sep  6 10:40:26 vagrant kernel: [37327.565248] init: tomcat main process (5862) terminated with status 126
./syslog:Sep  6 10:40:26 vagrant kernel: [37327.565262] init: tomcat main process ended, respawning
./syslog:Sep  6 10:40:26 vagrant kernel: [37327.574053] init: tomcat main process (5866) terminated with status 126
./syslog:Sep  6 10:40:26 vagrant kernel: [37327.574061] init: tomcat main process ended, respawning
./syslog:Sep  6 10:40:26 vagrant kernel: [37327.582124] init: tomcat main process (5870) terminated with status 126
./syslog:Sep  6 10:40:26 vagrant kernel: [37327.582132] init: tomcat main process ended, respawning
./syslog:Sep  6 10:40:26 vagrant kernel: [37327.590571] init: tomcat main process (5874) terminated with status 126
./syslog:Sep  6 10:40:26 vagrant kernel: [37327.590579] init: tomcat main process ended, respawning
./syslog:Sep  6 10:40:26 vagrant kernel: [37327.598389] init: tomcat main process (5878) terminated with status 126
./syslog:Sep  6 10:40:26 vagrant kernel: [37327.598397] init: tomcat main process ended, respawning
./syslog:Sep  6 10:40:26 vagrant kernel: [37327.606201] init: tomcat main process (5882) terminated with status 126
./syslog:Sep  6 10:40:26 vagrant kernel: [37327.606208] init: tomcat respawning too fast, stopped
./auth.log:Sep  6 09:41:00 vagrant sudo:  vagrant : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/vagrant ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/sbin/groupadd tomcat
./auth.log:Sep  6 09:41:01 vagrant groupadd[5547]: group added to /etc/group: name=tomcat, GID=1000
./auth.log:Sep  6 09:41:01 vagrant groupadd[5547]: group added to /etc/gshadow: name=tomcat
./auth.log:Sep  6 09:41:01 vagrant groupadd[5547]: new group: name=tomcat, GID=1000
./auth.log:Sep  6 09:41:09 vagrant sudo:  vagrant : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/vagrant ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/sbin/useradd -s /bin/false -g tomcat -d /opt/tomcat tomcat
./auth.log:Sep  6 09:41:09 vagrant useradd[5552]: new user: name=tomcat, UID=1000, GID=1000, home=/opt/tomcat, shell=/bin/false
./auth.log:Sep  6 10:02:51 vagrant sudo:  vagrant : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/vagrant ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/mkdir /opt/tomcat
./auth.log:Sep  6 10:03:18 vagrant sudo:  vagrant : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/vagrant ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/tar xvf apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M10.tar.gz -C /opt/tomcat --strip-components=1
./auth.log:Sep  6 10:03:31 vagrant sudo:  vagrant : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/opt/tomcat ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/chgrp -R tomcat conf
./auth.log:Sep  6 10:03:37 vagrant sudo:  vagrant : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/opt/tomcat ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/chmod g+rwx conf
./auth.log:Sep  6 10:03:42 vagrant sudo:  vagrant : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/opt/tomcat ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/chmod g+r conf/*
./auth.log:Sep  6 10:03:56 vagrant sudo:  vagrant : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/opt/tomcat ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/chown -R tomcat work/ temp/ logs/
./auth.log:Sep  6 10:05:06 vagrant sudo:  vagrant : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/opt/tomcat ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/nano /etc/init/tomcat.conf
./auth.log:Sep  6 10:05:39 vagrant sudo:  vagrant : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/opt/tomcat ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/nano /etc/init/tomcat.conf
./auth.log:Sep  6 10:06:23 vagrant sudo:  vagrant : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/opt/tomcat ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/nano /etc/init/tomcat.conf
./auth.log:Sep  6 10:07:21 vagrant sudo:  vagrant : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/opt/tomcat ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/sbin/initctl reload-configuration
./auth.log:Sep  6 10:07:26 vagrant sudo:  vagrant : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/opt/tomcat ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/sbin/initctl start tomcat
./auth.log:Sep  6 10:23:58 vagrant sudo:  vagrant : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/opt/tomcat ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/sbin/service tomcat7 status
./auth.log:Sep  6 10:24:03 vagrant sudo:  vagrant : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/opt/tomcat ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/sbin/service tomcat status
./auth.log:Sep  6 10:24:09 vagrant sudo:  vagrant : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/opt/tomcat ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/sbin/service tomcat start
./auth.log:Sep  6 10:24:37 vagrant sudo:  vagrant : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/opt/tomcat ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/sbin/service tomcat status
./auth.log:Sep  6 10:28:32 vagrant sudo:  vagrant : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/opt/tomcat ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/sbin/service tomcat status
./auth.log:Sep  6 10:31:22 vagrant sudo:  vagrant : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/opt/tomcat ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/nano /etc/init/tomcat.conf
./auth.log:Sep  6 10:38:33 vagrant sudo:  vagrant : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/opt/tomcat ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/sbin/service tomcat stop
./auth.log:Sep  6 10:38:41 vagrant sudo:  vagrant : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/opt/tomcat ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/sbin/service tomcat start
./auth.log:Sep  6 10:38:51 vagrant sudo:  vagrant : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/opt/tomcat ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/sbin/service tomcat restart
./auth.log:Sep  6 10:40:18 vagrant sudo:  vagrant : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/opt/tomcat ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/sbin/initctl reload-configuration
./auth.log:Sep  6 10:40:25 vagrant sudo:  vagrant : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/opt/tomcat ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/sbin/initctl start tomcat
./auth.log:Sep  6 10:56:48 vagrant sudo:  vagrant : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/opt/tomcat ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/apt-get update
./auth.log:Sep  6 10:57:28 vagrant sudo:  vagrant : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/opt/tomcat ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/apt-get install -y mysql-server
./auth.log:Sep  6 11:04:44 vagrant sudo:  vagrant : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/opt/tomcat ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/mysql_secure_installation
./auth.log:Sep  6 11:05:14 vagrant sudo:  vagrant : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/opt/tomcat ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/mysql_install_db
./auth.log:Sep  6 11:05:43 vagrant sudo:  vagrant : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/opt/tomcat ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/etc/init.d/mysql start
./auth.log:Sep  6 12:11:39 vagrant sudo:  vagrant : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/opt/tomcat ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/chown root:root logs/
./auth.log:Sep  6 12:11:55 vagrant sudo:  vagrant : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/opt/tomcat ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/chown tomcat:root logs/
./auth.log:Sep  6 12:12:58 vagrant sudo:  vagrant : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/opt/tomcat ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/bash
vagrant@vagrant:/var/log$
```

Comment: Can you show the log please ?

Comment: Added directory listing of logs directory in original post. Directory is empty.

Comment: If you use it as a service, maybe there is some logs in /var/log/syslog or another logs in /var/log

Comment: See original post for log directory and syslog messages with tomcat in it. Will be offline for 8 hours now (sleep) but will be back after that. Any ideas are appreciated. Cheers.

Comment: It says tomcat process terminated with status 126: Command invoked cannot execute

Answer (score 8):

Try this :

```
cd /opt
sudo chown -R tomcat:tomcat tomcat/
```

I had same problem and now tomcat starts just fine :)